# Graphical modeler: QGIS Field calculator don't consider real value of the attribute layer

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to create a tool with graphical modeler of QGIS where I add a new attribute which represents length of the line divided by an certain number of interval informed in his attribute table. [image]

For that I use Field calculator algorithm where I write the expression (In pre-calculated value):

```
$length  / @AttributDivisionnumber
```

I tried to use:

```
$length / attribute(@AttributDivisionnumber)
```

[image]
[image]

But I have always the same error message `No node roots`.
[image]
I understand than Qgis consider than @AttributDivisionnumber is not a number when I use graphical modeler ... but idk how change it. Someone have any idea?

Comment: What does the error translate to in english?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`eval()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#eval) because the variable returns only the name of the field as a string, not the value(s) of this field:

```
$length / eval(@AttributDivisionnumber)
```

> eval() Evaluates an expression which is passed in a string. Useful to
> expand dynamic parameters passed as context variables or fields.

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't work, it keeps putting me 'No root node' ...